# Using numpy array to output the nth value in a list

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, function, numpy, reduce

Down below is a function that looks out for the common numbers within 3 lists `MNDW_drawdown, PRC_overall_prec, TTS_Total_Trades` using a numpy and the reduce function. However the output is in the form of a numpy array ,is there any way I could convert it into a list form. I want to print the nth value within a list using the `reduced` so it will be `list_[reduced]`.
Code:

```
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np

list_ = [ 5268, 6760,  6761 ... 15149, 15150, 15151]
def intersect(l1, l2, l3) :#function
    reduced = reduce(np.intersect1d, (l1, l2, l3))
    print(reduced)  
intersect(MNDW_drawdown, PRC_overall_prec, TTS_Total_Trades) #calling function
```

Reduced Output:

```
[11858 11860 11861 11862 11863 11864 11865 11866 11867 11868 11869 11870
 13548 13549 13550 13551 13552 13553 13554 13555 13556 13557 13558 13559]
```

Comment: `reduced.tolist()` ? this convert the numpy array to  list.

Comment: Why do you need a list? Arrays have basically the same interface. Also, your example is by no means an MCVE. Please fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use the `.tolist()` function as suggested in other answers. Another way is not to use numpy in the first place, but the built-in `set` type, which provides the `.intersection` method. Convert the first list to a `set` and then chain the `.intersection` method for the remaining arguments. The result, however, will be a `set`, too, so you have convert to list anyway.

```
def intersect(a: list, b: list, c: list) -> list:
    return list(set(a).intersection(b).intersection(c))
```

Note that the result will not be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is `reduced.tolist()`